# PDO vs MYSQLI, Prepared Statemens and Binding Parameters

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, parameters, prepared-statement

I have this very question to clear things up. I read some documentation and comments around but still somethings are just not clear enough.

- I understand PDO offers more drivers which would certainly is a plus if you would ever change your database type.
- As said on another post, PDO doesnt offer true prepared statements but mysqli does so it would be safer to use MYSQLI
- Benchmarks looks similar, (did not test it myself but checked around on the web for a few benchmarks)
- Being object oriented is not an issue for me since mysqli is catching up. But would be nice to benchmark procedural mysqli vs PDO since procedural is supposed to be slightly faster.

But here is my question, with prepared statement, do we have to use parameter binding with the data we use in our statement? good practice or have to? I understand prepared statements are good perfermance-wise if you run the same query multiple times but it is enough to secure the query itself? or binding parameters is a must? What exactly do the binding parameters and how it works to protect the data from sql injection? Also would be appreciated if you point our any misunderstanding about the statements I made above.

Comment: [Should you use prepared statements for their escaping only?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16365669/285587)

Comment: what is the post stating PDO doesn't support native prepared statements? It have to be deleted or at least downvoted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection, Quote=> "The important thing to realize here is that PDO by default does NOT do true prepared statements. It emulates them (for MySQL).", May be I misunderstood...

Comment: The key word is "by default". So, it is customizable behavior, however by default set to most compatible mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short,

- **Binding is a must**, being a cornerstone of protection, no matter if it is supported by a native driver or not. It's the idea of substitution that matters.
- The difference is **negligible** in either safety and performance.
- **Performance is the last thing to consider.** There is NO API that is considerable slower than other. It is not a class or a function that may cause whatever performance problem but a data manipulation or a bad algorithm. Optimize your queries, not mere functions to call them.
- If you are going to use a raw bare API, then PDO is the only choice. While wrapped in a higher level class, mysqli seems more preferable for mysql.
- Both mysqli and PDO lack bindings for the identifiers and keywords. In this case a **whitelist**-based protection must be implemented. Here is my article with the ready made example, [Adding a field name to the SQL query dynamically](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/order_by)

Comment: If we properly use prepared statements and bind parameters as are supposed to, then we still consider using this safeMysql or create our own class? I understand it is good for "convenient because it makes application code short and meaningful, without useless repetitions, making it Extra DRY" as mentioned on their website.

Comment: Because "Both mysqli and PDO lacks binding for the important literals" - identifiers for example. Try to bind a field name either in mysqli or PDO and see. IN statement may become a problem too. The very idea of safeMysql class is to give a placeholder for the *everything* that may be added to the query, not only 1 or 2 data types as mysqli does.